# What is the difference between modprobe and dkms?

Tags: dkms, modprobe

Noob question here....
I read about modprobe and dkms and it seems to me they do the same thing, so what is the difference?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

#### Modprobe

Loads and runs a kernel module

#### dkms

Compiles and installs a kernel module from source for the specified kernel (current running kernel if none are specified.

#### To autoload modules at boot

Edit the file  `/etc/modules`. add each module you want to load one per line.

Example file contents:

```
# /etc/modules: kernel modules to load at boot time.
#
# This file contains the names of kernel modules that should be loaded
# at boot time, one per line. Lines beginning with "#" are ignored.

fuse
lp
sbp2
cpufreq_userspace
powernow-k8
```

Comment: Thanks!
And when running modprobe it will save this state for next boot of course, right?

Comment: added directions on how to autoload modules